# Hypothetical question regarding styling <body> and <html> differently using the same stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am using a self-made template from Dreamweaver (which includes a header and a footer) and I use this template to create new pages from it.

Many tutorials style the body and/or HTML tags inside the stylesheet, which would be fine if you were only creating one page, however I have multiple pages attached to one stylesheet.

By following any of the tutorials mentioned above it would completely change the layout on my other pages since they are all linked to the same stylesheet, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you can link the same style sheet to multiple HTML pages. You'd just have to write your CSS accordingly.
Example:

.PG1-BOX,
.PG2-BOX{
}

Furthermore, keeping all your external CSS in one style sheet is better for maintainability and reduces loading times. If you had multiple style sheets, the user has to request them all and then download them all whereas maintaining just one stylesheet would reduce this process.

Comment: No sorry I haven’t explained it very well. Some people from tutorials style the html and body tags (say with display:flex) but I already have a header and a footer styled with (say display:block) and by styling the html and body it would mess up my OG design, is there a way around this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you have a codepen or anything we can see?

Comment: I accidentally sent my comment by pressing  intro without finishing the comment, if you read it now it may make more sense.

Comment: Okay so, sorry if I still misunderstand. Whatever style is applied to an element after declaring it already once in the style sheet will override it's previous entry. Say, if you style the body with `display: flex`  and then declare a container later with `display: block` then the container will override the body's declaration. That is the cascading nature of CSS.